# How to count in access

Tags: ms-access

can experts please show me how to count the below? Basically each time there are 4 samples produced. I just want to count for each cell(total over al the time periods T1, T2,T3), the number of times "16" occurs, 32, occurs, etc. Please advise. I can do in Excel, but I want to use access as its a bigfile.

```
Cell    Time    Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 Sample4
A1  T1  16  16  32  Unavailable
B1  T1  16  16  32  Unavailable
C1  T1  160 320 320 Unavailable
A1  T2  80  80  80  Unavailable
B1  T2  80  96  Unavailable Unavailable
C1  T2  160 320 Unavailable Unavailable
A1  T3  16  80  80  96
B1  T3  16  16  16  16
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a union query:

```
Select
    Cell, [Time], Sample1 As Sample
From 
    YourTable
Union All
Select
    Cell, [Time], Sample2 As Sample
From 
    YourTable
Union All
Select
    Cell, [Time], Sample3 As Sample
From 
    YourTable
Union All
Select
    Cell, [Time], Sample4 As Sample
From 
    YourTable
```

Save this and use it as source in a new query:

```
Select
    Sample, Count(*) As Total
From
    SavedQuery
Group By 
    Sample
```

Comment: Hi,wow thanks for quick reply! I am a bit of a rookie.I just copied and pasted the union query but error message pops up saying "syntax error in query.incomplete query clause". Please advise.

Comment: Well, it was too fast. Please use the corrected code.

Comment: Thanks again. I have used the idea and it seems to work. I actually have 60 samples. I "union all" up till 50th sample. On the 51st, it just says Query too complex! So I broke it in to 2 query and add them together. Thanks.